# quel est le mot français pour "minus sign"?

Tags: mathématiques

Parfois, les mathématiciens soustraient des nombres à d'autres nombres.

En mathematiques, dans 《`x - y`》 quel est le nom du symbole 《`-`》 ?

Comment: Easily found in a dictionary. [e.g.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/minus) "used to show subtraction **moins** *Ten minus two equals eight (10 – 2 = 8)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le nom de ce symbole est "*signe de soustraction*" et aussi "*signe moins*". En lisant on dit seulement "moins".

- « x - y » se lit "x moins y".

Il existe un choix de  vocabulaire qui n'a pas cours dans l'enseignement sauf peut-être encore dans les écoles primaires et dans le langage quotidien ; on l'utilise lorsqu'on fait des opérations de soustraction ; on le trouve dans la littérature surtout au 18<sup>e</sup> et au 19<sup>e</sup> siècles mais encore au 20<sup>e</sup>.

x - y = z : y **oté** de x **[Il reste]/[donne]** z (*x, y, z doivent être des chiffres ou de petits nombres, pas des lettres (pas d'habitude).*)

Parfois, on utilise encore « soustrait » à la place de « oté », mais on ne trouve plus cette option dans la littérature.

([Lec̣ons d'arithmétique théorique et pratique — 1911](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Lec%CC%A3ons_d_arithm%C3%A9tique_th%C3%A9orique_et_p/22JbAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22ot%C3%A9+de%22&dq=%22ot%C3%A9+de%22&printsec=frontcover)) 5 ôté de 6 , il reste 1

([Ecole et la Vie - Volume 24,Numéros 1 à 39 — 1940](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Ecole_et_la_Vie/SccmAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22ot%C3%A9+de%22&dq=%22ot%C3%A9+de%22&printsec=frontcover) ) 1 ôté de 29 , il reste 28

([Avec des nombres et des lignes: (récréations mathématiques) — 1942](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Avec_des_nombres_et_des_lignes/5PpUAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22ot%C3%A9+de%22&dq=%22ot%C3%A9+de%22&printsec=frontcover))   2 Oté de 6 donne 4

Comment: "y soustrait de x" n'est pas usuel du tout.